# Memory occupied by a chunk of a stream

Tags: node.js

```
if(url==='/message' && method==='POST') {
    const body=[];
    req.on('data',(chunk)=>{
        body.push(chunk);
    });
    req.on('end', ()=>{
    const parsedbody=Buffer.concat(body).toString();
    const text=parsedbody.split('=')[1];
    fs.writeFileSync('message.txt',text);
});
```

what is the memory occupied by each of the chunks received? How memory is managed n such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a stream, you can either use `chunk.length`. Alternatively, you could use `readable.readableHighWaterMark`/`writable.writableHighWaterMark`. They'll be the maximum size a chunk will ever be before the stream resumes to flowing mode.

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_constructor_new_stream_writable_options